# Noisy Occupancy Map with Zed Camera

Tags: slam, navigation, stereo-camera, occupancy-grid, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to create an occupancy grid using a ZED stereo camera along with rtabmap_ros. My results are very noisy and I am wondering if the problem is with the ZED camera, or with my rtabmap_ros config, or both.  Can anyone verify whether or not rtabmap can deal with this level of sensor noise.

**Details:**

- ZED camera calibrated using the calibration tool found in /usr/local/zed
- Running on NVIDIA TX1, Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo
- Indoor well light room, ZED mounted on mobile robot being joysticked

**Pictures:**

Here is a sample of a map I have generated
[image: image description]

And here is an example of the depth cloud at one instant
[image: image description]

As you can see the depth cloud is fairly noisy, but what sensor data isn't.

**Launch File:**

```
<launch>

  <include file="$(find zed_wrapper)/launch/zed_tf.launch" />

  <arg name="svo_file" default=""/>
  
  <group ns="camera">
    <node name="zed_wrapper_node" pkg="zed_wrapper" type="zed_wrapper_node" args="$(arg svo_file)" >

      <param name="resolution"            value="2" />
      <param name="quality"               value="1" />
      <param name="sensing_mode"          value="1" />
      <param name="frame_rate"            value="30" />
      <param name="odometry_DB"           value="" />
      <param name="openni_depth_mode"     value="0" />

      <param name="rgb_topic"             value="rgb/image_rect_color" />
      <param name="rgb_cam_info_topic"    value="rgb/camera_info" />
      <param name="rgb_frame_id"          value="/zed_link" />

      <param name="left_topic"            value="left/image_rect_color" />
      <param name="left_cam_info_topic"   value="left/camera_info" />
      <param name="left_frame_id"         value="/zed_link" />

      <param name="right_topic"           value="right/image_rect_color" />
      <param name="right_cam_info_topic"  value="right/camera_info" />
      <param name="right_frame_id"        value="/zed_link" />

      <param name="depth_topic"           value="depth/image_rect_color" />
      <param name="depth_cam_info_topic"  value="depth/camera_info" />
      <param name="depth_frame_id"        value="/zed_link" />

      <param name="point_cloud_topic"     value="point_cloud/cloud" />
      <param name="cloud_frame_id"        value="/zed_link" />

      <param name="odometry_topic"                value="odom" />
      <param name="odometry_frame_id"             value="/zed_link" />
      <param name="odometry_transform_frame_id"   value="/zed_tracked_frame" />

      <param name="visual_odometry"       value="false" />
      <param name="odometry_topic"            value="/odometry/filtered_map" />


    </node>
  </group>

      <!--Visual SLAM: args: "delete_db_on_start" and "udebug" -->
      <node name="rtabmap" pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" output="screen" args="--delete_db_on_start" >
         <param name="frame_id"         type="string" value="base_link"/>
         <param name="subscribe_stereo" type="bool" value="false"/>
         <param name="subscribe_depth"  type="bool" value="true"/>

         <remap from="rgb/image"  to="/camera/rgb/image_rect_color"/>
         <remap from="rgb/camera_info"  to="/camera/rgb/camera_info"/>
         <remap from="/depth/image"   to="/camera/depth/image_rect_color"/>
         <remap from="odom" to="/odometry/filtered_map"/>

         <param name="queue_size" type="int" value="30"/>

         <!-- RTAB-Map's parameters -->
         <param name="Rtabmap/TimeThr"                   type="string" value="700"/>
         <param name="Grid/DepthDecimation"              type="string" value="4"/>
         <param name="Grid/FlatObstacleDetected"         type="string" value="true"/>
         <param name="Kp/MaxFeatures"                    type="string" value="200"/>
         <param name="Kp/MaxDepth"                       type="string" value="10"/>
         <param name="Kp/DetectorStrategy"               type="string" value="0"/>   <!-- use SURF -->
         <param name="SURF/HessianThreshold"             type="string" value="1000"/>
         <param name="Vis/EstimationType"                type="string" value="0"/>   <!-- 0=3D->3D, 1=3D->2D (PnP) -->
         <param name="RGBD/LoopClosureReextractFeatures" type="string" value="true"/>
         <param name="Vis/MaxDepth"                      type="string" value="10"/>
      </node>

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246668/noisy-occupancy-map-with-zed-camera/) by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 545 on 2016-10-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ankursingh0820](https://answers.ros.org/users/31244/ankursingh0820/) on 2017-07-18**:
Can you please tell in detailed steps me how I can run your launch file..since I am a novice
thanks in advance

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2017-07-18**:
I got this launch file from here (https://www.stereolabs.com/documentation/guides/using-zed-with-ros/introduction.html). Follow the steps on that page to run the launch file. Let me know if you have any questions.

**Comment by [ankursingh0820](https://answers.ros.org/users/31244/ankursingh0820/) on 2017-07-18**:
ZED (Init) >> WARNING: FPS is too low to enable positional tracking and spatial mapping. Consider using PERFORMANCE parameters
[WARN] [1500391893.105831732]: /zed/rtabmap: Did not receive data since 5 seconds! Make sure the input topics are published.

found this error,fps-30,but usb is 2.0

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2017-07-18**:
In zed_camera.launch change the quality value to 1 if it isn't already. What computer are you running the ZED camera on? It needs a decent GPU to run.

**Comment by [ankursingh0820](https://answers.ros.org/users/31244/ankursingh0820/) on 2017-07-18**:
That's Xeon 8gb, with nvidia gtx580 with gpu memory of 1.5gb memory

**Comment by [neilj244](https://answers.ros.org/users/31294/neilj244/) on 2017-07-21**:
hi im also a colleague of ankursingh0820 i am running it on a jetson tx1.I still get the warning FPS is too low.But there is no output generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Change the zed_wrapper_node quality parameter to "3" for the highest quality depth image.

Options:
0: None
1: Performance
2: Medium
3: Quality

[Reference](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-ros-wrapper#dynamic-parameter)

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2016-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0